# Unity Raycasting doesn't seem to like diagonals

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am trying to use raycasting to show the correct cursor when looking at an enemy compared to not. I was having some problem in that it only seemed to work when staring straight at the enemy on a straight line, so I checked with Debug.DrawRay, and turning on the debug line , looked in a circle atop my block, then turned debug off, to find this oddity -

[image]

It is looking like it doesnt try to raycast at a diagonal, which confused me.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraRaycaster : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Layer[] LayerPriorities = {
        Layer.Wall,
        Layer.Enemy,
        Layer.Walkable,

    };

    [SerializeField] 
    private float _distanceToBackground = 100f;

    [SerializeField] 
    private GameObject _raycastObject;

    public bool Debug = false;
    public Layer DebugLayer = Layer.RaycastEndStop;

    private Camera _viewCamera;

    private RaycastHit _hit;
    public RaycastHit Hit
    {
        get { return _hit; }
    }

    Layer _layerHit;
    public Layer LayerHit
    {
        get { return _layerHit; }
    }

    private void Start() // TODO Awake?
    {
        _viewCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Look for and return priority layer hit
        foreach (var layer in LayerPriorities)
        {
            var hit = RaycastForLayer(layer);
            if (hit.HasValue)
            {
                _hit = hit.Value;
                _layerHit = layer;
                return;
            }
        }

        // Otherwise return background hit
        _hit.distance = _distanceToBackground;
        _layerHit = Layer.RaycastEndStop;
    }

    private RaycastHit? RaycastForLayer(Layer layer)
    {
        var trans = this.transform;
        if (_raycastObject != null)
        {
            trans = _raycastObject.transform;
        }
        var layerMask = 1 << (int)layer; // See Unity docs for mask     formation
        //Ray ray = viewCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit hit; // used as an out parameter
        var hasHit = Physics.Raycast(trans.position, trans.forward, out hit,     _distanceToBackground,layerMask);
        if (Debug && (DebugLayer==Layer.RaycastEndStop ||     DebugLayer==layer))
        {
            var debugColour=hasHit?Color.green:Color.red;
            UnityEngine.Debug.DrawRay(trans.position,     trans.forward,debugColour,_distanceToBackground,true);
        }
        if (hasHit)
        {
            return hit;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code is not working you should edit your question and post that code otherwise someone might put an answer with that exact code that's not working for you.

Comment: @Programmer donethat thankyou!

Comment: I see your code. What's the problem? I looked at the image and read this can't still tell what the issue is...

Comment: @Programmer notice how the raycasting shown in the image is only in 4 directions , missing the corners. That is even though I did a slow turn, it seems to not be casting between those areas.